# How To Add Automatic Jump Breaks In Blogger Posts

Tags: javascript, blogger

I know my question sounds weird to you but actually I am not going to ask how to create Auto Read More Summaries or post excerpts in blogger. Because there are multiple tutorials available on adding post excerpts in blogger on index pages. The problem is that the post still fully loads with page that makes blog slower. I have a blog with 120+ posts and I cannot add individually jump breaks in them by going to post editor. Is there any other way to automatically add jump breaks in posts (the actual jump break that can be added by post editor, not the post excerpts read more button) on index pages?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to utilize the new `snippet` operator. This will allow you to load in only a summary (which is controlled via `length` property) of post content on the index pages (aka homepage, pagination pages) Replace the instance of `<data:post.body/>` with the following code -

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType not in {"static_page", "item"}'>
  <b:eval expr='snippet(data:post.body, {length: 450, linebreaks: false, links: false})' />
  <a expr:href='data:post.url + &quot;#more&quot;' ><data:post.jumpText/></a>
<b:else/>
  <data:post.body/>
</b:if>
```

For more detailed documentation of the `snippet` operator -

> #### snippet(string, options)
>
> Produces a short snippet from an HTML string.
>
> **options**: Object specifying the snippeting options, which are:
>
> - **links**: boolean for whether to preserve anchors/links in the snippet.
>   Defaults to true.
> - **linebreaks**: boolean for whether to preserve linebreaks (tags) in the
>   snippet. Defaults to true.
> - **ellipsis**: boolean for whether to append an ellipsis (…) to the end of
>   the snippet. Defaults to true.
> - **length**: Number specifying the maximum length of the snippet.